# Did Brad Pitt play the Vanisher in Deadpool 2?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

In *Deadpool 2* there is a character named Vanisher. When we finally see this characters face

> once he dies

you see that it was someone who looks exactly like Brad Pitt. I've checked IMBb and it has stated that it was said actor but in the movie it looked a bit like CGI.

Was Brad Pitt the Vanisher?

Comment: If IMDb says that "the actor" was indeed _the actor_, do you have any reason to believe that he isn't the actor? I'm also unsure how stating that an actor was a character in a film is a spoiler?

Comment: @Edlothiad I guess not however in the movie we only see him once, So he may not have done the body acting and just had the small part.

Comment: @Edlothiad In the general case I would agree that stating an actor is present in a movie is probably not a spoiler.  However, in *this case* I can sort of see the validity of treating it as such.

Comment: Oh hell, it was? I thought it was Chris Pratt. I *did* spot Alan Tudyk and Matt Damon though

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes he was in the film

In an interview with Screen Rant, *Deadpool 2* co-writer Rhett Reese confirms that it was indeed Brad Pitt.

> Rhett Reese: Uh, Vanisher was a late add. It was the very last thing we shot on the Deadpool movie was Brad Pitt came to set. He agreed to play Vanisher in return for scale, which is a very, very low number, a low, low salary and a cup of coffee from Starbucks delivered to him by Ryan Reynolds. So Ryan had to hand over that coffee to Brad in order for him to do the part. He came in, he was willing to do it because his kids love Deadpool and he's a great guy. And uh, Ryan just asked him and he said yes, and next thing you know, boom, he's standing there, and we had, we had a ton of fun. It was about a half an hour shoot and he was on his way and it really adds a fun moment. You can hear people gasp.
>
> <sub>[What it Took For [SPOILER] to Cameo in Deadpool 2 -Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/deadpool-2-brad-pitt-cameo/)</sub>